# Ajax Post returning full aspx page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've tried to make a an ajax call to post to a webmethod, whenever I post it, it just returns the whole aspx page.
Here is the Ajax call:

```
var $jq =jQuery.noConflict();
    $jq.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default2.aspx/sortxml",
    data: xmlDoc,

        complete: function (xhr, status) {
    error: function (xhr, status, text) {
              console.log(xhr.status);
              console.log(xhr.text);
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
             }

        if (status === 'error' || !xhr.responseText) {

            alert(xhr.responseText);
            document.getElementById("response").value = xhr.responseText;
        }
        else {
            var data = xhr.responseText;
            //alert(data);
            document.getElementById("response").value = data;

        }
    }
```

and here is the webmethod, I simplified it massively this sits on the code behind a page called "Default2.aspx"

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
    public static string sortxml()
{
return ("hi");}
```

The form it pulls the data from is here:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<button onclick="cmdButtonSend();" type="button" >Call Component Engine</button>
    <br /><p>
<asp:TextBox id="TextInput" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Wrap="false"  ></asp:TextBox>

         </p>
    <asp:TextBox id="response" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Wrap="true"  ></asp:TextBox>
     <p class ="tim">  Set Timeout
    <asp:TextBox id="timer1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Wrap="false"  ></asp:TextBox></p>

           </form>
```

When I run the ajax call it returns the whole aspx page the form is on.

Why is this?

EDIT: The Ajax call is part of a JavaScript method which is called as part of the cmdButtonSend(); method.

Comment: Hi, some advice if you want people to help: 1) Fix you code blocks - you *can* spend enough time on the question to fix, for instance, the indentation if you expect other people to spend time helping you. 2) Show how things hang together. I don't see how the javascript gets call. Is it `cmdButtonSend();`.

Comment: Had a little change around of the code and made it clearer how things fit together

Comment: add contentType and dataType properties to $.ajax call. Also if you are sending data you should have parameters in your webmethod to accept that data.

Comment: I am just curious, why can't we use ASP.net Built in Update Panels ?(Assuming this is web forms project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what was causing the issues. 
I had to make it so that it knew it was sending Json and expect it back. This required slight alterations to the ajax call and the webmethod.

```
var $jq =jQuery.noConflict();
    $jq.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default2.aspx/sortxml",
        data: "{XMLDOC: 'xmlDoc'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function (xhr, status) {
    error: function (xhr, status, text) {
              console.log(xhr.status);
              console.log(xhr.text);
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
             }

        if (status === 'error' || !xhr.responseText) {

            alert(xhr.responseText);
            document.getElementById("response").value = xhr.responseText;
        }
        else {
            var data = xhr.responseText;
            //alert(data);
            document.getElementById("response").value = data;

        }
    }
```

notice the introduction of the

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
```

and then had to alter the data section

```
data: "{XMLDOC: 'xmlDoc'}",
```

In the webmethod I had to just then include the new XMLDOC variable and it works

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
    public static string sortxml(string XMLDOC)
    {

return ("hi");}
```